# iPhone disconnected USB connection overnight and there are no system logs

Tags: ios, xcode, logging, ios-simulator, google-fabric

I needed to run a long test to see what's making my app crash. So I set the Mac to not sleep and I ran the app on the iPhone connected via USB overnight. In the morning, I found that the iPhone had disconnected during the night.

I looked for in Console and Xcode for device logs and I found there were none at all on the phone, therefore no history of what happened during the night. Logs began after the moment I reconnected the phone to the Mac.

I downloaded the app container and found no useful evidence of what happened.

iOS is 12.4 and Xcode is 10.3.

What can be done to ensure there is some evidence of what caused the crash? Other than filling the app with fprintf's going to a custom log file. Also I am using Fabric.

Answer (score 0):

Do the same thing again, but this time with a camera looking at the PC. Maybe you can grab some evidence from the recording next day. Modern solutions for modern problems.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Touch ID and Passcode

Check if USB Accessories has been turned off. Your device may have disconnected then failed to reconnect due to this feature restricting access to the device if it is disconnected for more than an hour.

Change this setting, replace your cable or use a different USB port then try running it again.